# Importing Git repo of Bitbucke in to TFS Git

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

> "Microsoft has added an even easier way to import any Git repo into
>   your VSTS account.  You can now import it directly from the Team
>   Services:
>
> From the Repository dropdown list, select Import repository. Enter the
>   clone URL of your source repo, your credentials, and the name of your
>   new repository Click Import, wait a few seconds… Your repository,
>   including all history, and branches is now available in VSTS!"

Source "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Importing%20Git%20repo%20of%20Bitbucke%20in%20to%20TFS%20Git%20".

I have tried providing require details to initiate code from external git repository to VSTS git but ending up with errors.

> Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following
>   reasons: Clone URL is incorrect. Credentials are incorrect. Clone URL
>   points to an empty repository.

How to proceed further?

Comment: The error message gave you three possibilities. Have you investigated those three possibilities?

Comment: Which one are you using, on-premise TFS or VSTS? For VSTS, the url should be something like this `https://{useraccount}.visualstudio.com`

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your response I am using on-premise TFS, I have verified all the three, it looks fine for me. Still having the same problem.

Comment: Could you share the format of your clone url?

Comment: @user9473385 Any update on this, have the issue been solved?

Comment: Hello Eddie, below is the format that I am using.
https://username@git.xxxxxx.com/xx/xx/xxx.git
@Patrick I haven't resolved yet!

Comment: I think there is something possibly wrong with the distribution of git shipped with TFS on-prem. I get the same behaviour in TFS 2018 Update 1. If I attempt to clone a github repository using the distribution on the application tier (in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2018\Version Control Proxy\MinGit`), under the application tier service account I get the following error: `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'`.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you first go through the tutorial-- [Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository?view=vsts). This guide shows you how to import an existing Git repo from GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab, or other location into a new or empty existing repo in your VSTS project.

If you are using on-premise  TFS, you must have **TFS 2017 Update 1 or higher**.

- If the source repo is publicly available, just enter the clone URL of
  the source repository and a name for your new Git repository.
- If the source repository is private but can be accessed using basic
  authentication (username-password, personal access token, etc.),
  select **Requires authorization** and enter the your credentials.

Double confirm this and follow the step in tutorial, then try again see if the issue solved.

Besides, just like Daniel suggested the error message also gave you three possibilities. You could investigate those three possibilities to narrow down the issue.